# consulta preparada PDO-PHP

Tags: php, pdo

Estoy creando un CRUD, similar a un to do list. Tengo un problema que cuando quiero hacer una consulta para ver si existe en la base datos la cédula o el correo me sale un error, con mysqli no tengo problema, la cuestión es que cuando uso la extensión PDO no me sale el mismo resultado me sale error tras error, aquí el código:

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['registro_cedula']) || isset($_POST['registro_cedula']) == true) {
session_start();
include_once 'conexion.php';
$cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
$nombres = $_POST['nombres'];
$apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
$correo = $_POST['correo'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];

if (empty($cedula) || empty($nombres) || empty($apellidos) || empty($correo) || 
empty($telefono)) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Llena los campos vacíos';
    $_SESSION['color-error'] = 'danger';
    header('location:../index.php?error=invalid-empty-fields');
    exit();
}elseif (!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $cedula)) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = '<strong>Cedula</strong> solo admite números';
    $_SESSION['color-error'] = 'danger';
    header('location:../index.php?error=invalid-cedula');
    exit();
}elseif (strlen($cedula) > 8 || strlen($cedula) < 7) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Escriba correctamente la <strong>Cédula</strong><br>Ejemplo: 
 20907509';
    $_SESSION['color-error'] = 'danger';
    header('location:../index.php?error=invalid-cedula');
    exit();
}elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-z A-Z]+$/", $nombres) || empty($nombres)) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Escriba su <strong>Nombre</strong>';
    $_SESSION['color-error'] = 'danger';
    header('location:../index.php?error=invalid-nombre');
    exit();
}elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-z A-Z]+$/", $apellidos) || empty($apellidos)) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Escriba su <strong>Apellido</strong>';
    $_SESSION['color-error'] = 'danger';
    header('location:../index.php?error=invalid-apellido');
    exit();
}elseif (!filter_var($correo, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) || empty($correo)) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Escriba un <strong>Correo</strong> válido';
    $_SESSION['color-error'] = 'danger';
    header('location:../index.php?error=invalid-correo');
    exit();
}elseif (!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $telefono) || empty($telefono)) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Escriba un número<strong>Telefónico</strong> válido';
    $_SESSION['color-error'] = 'danger';
    header('location:../index.php?error=invalid-telefono');
    exit();
}else{
    $sql = "SELECT cedula(*) from users where cedula = :cedula ";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt = execute();
    while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Esta <strong>Cedula</strong> existe';
        $_SESSION['color-error'] = 'danger';
        header('location:../index.php?error=invalid-cedula');
        exit();
      }
   }
 }
```

Cuando estoy en mi formulario y ejecuto la app, me sale este bendito error, ayuda! he probado varios métodos me sale lo mismo >:(

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function query() in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\cedula-identidad\db\register_cedula.php:50 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\cedula-identidad\db\register_cedula.php on line 50
```

Comment: El error que aparece se refiere a `query`, pero en tu código no veo que llames a `query` en ninguna parte. Puede ser que estés usando una clase envoltorio de PDO (una clase que creaste tú mismo y que devuelve un objeto PDO) pero quizá esa clase no está bien escrita como envoltorio o no extiende de PDO realmente o no tienes PDO instalado en tu PHP. Es lo que hace pensar el `Call to undefined function query()`

Comment: Esta línea `$stmt = execute();` no debería ser así: `$stmt->execute();`

Comment: Cierto @Aprendiz. Además, debe pasar el parámetro de la consulta preparada, algo así: `$stmt->execute( array (':cedula'=>$cedula) );` pero como quiera, el error que aparece indica que no está reconociendo el método `query` de PDO. No tiene para nada que ver con este código, el cual también es erróneo.

Answer (score 1):

Como te señalaron, y por la naturaleza de PDO, todo se desprende de métodos y factorías del objeto `$conn` de manera que algo como `$variable = execute()` propio del enfoque procedural nunca aplicaría.

Para tu caso de uso, te falta usar el método `execute` sobre el objeto PDOStatement `$stmt`

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

**Pero...**

le diste el placeholder `:consulta` a la sentencia, de manera que no puedes ejecutar sin más. Tienes que asignarlo al vuelo:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([':cedula' => $cedula]);
```

O bien bindear el valor de antemano:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':cedula', $cedula, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Y ya que estamos en eso, no tiene sentido hacer un bucle para comprobar si la céluda existe. Mejor ocupa `fetchAll` trayendo sólo una columna. Es más rápido y eficiente:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':cedula', $cedula, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

if(count($result)>0) {
  // La cédula existe
}
```

Como siempre puede haber imponderables, es sano envolver todo esto en un try-catch:

```
try {
    $stmt = $stmt->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([':cedula' => $cedula]);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
    if(count($result)>0) {
        $_SESSION['error']       = 'Esta <strong>Cedula</strong> existe';
        $_SESSION['color-error'] = 'danger';
        header('location:../index.php?error=invalid-cedula');
        exit();
    }
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
}
```